# Simple vector cross product question.

Tags: vectors, classical-mechanics

How do you compute the cross product of two vectors in the following form:

$r_{u} = \cos(\theta)\textbf{x} + \sin(\theta)\textbf{y}$

$r_{v} = -\cos(\theta)\textbf{x} - \sin(\theta)\textbf{y}$

I have completely forgotten. This is just an example I created off the top of my head.

Comment: Are you doing cross product in 3 dimensions?

Comment: Quite simply,
$$r_u\times r_v=-\cos\theta\sin\theta+\sin\theta\cos\theta=0$$

Comment: Thanks, Sanath. I thought that might be the case. I assumed the cross product ended up with a vector, though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are parallel ($r_u=-r_v$) so the cross product is by the property of antisymmetry equal to zero.